# Best sources for communication complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, communication-complexity, books

What are some of the best sources (books and papers) to motivate and learn communication complexity on its own and in connection with its relation to computational complexity theory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Books:

- Eyal Kushilevitz and Noam Nisan, "[Communication Complexity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052102983X)", 2006.
- Stasys Jukna, "Boolean Function Complexity: Advances and Frontiers", 2012. (Part II of the book is dedicated to Communication Complexity.)

Articles:

- Alexander Razborov, "[Communication Complexity](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/cc.pdf)".

Lecture Notes:

- Toni Pitassi, "[Communication Complexity, Information Complexity and Applications](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Courses/CommComplexity2/CS2429.html)", 2012
- Ran Raz, "[Circuit Complexity and Communication Complexity](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~ranraz/lecturenotes/)".

Also check [Sasha's remarks about communication complexity](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/teaching/index.html).

Comment: The recent book by Stasys Jukna is fantastic http://www.amazon.com/Boolean-Function-Complexity-Algorithms-Combinatorics/dp/3642245072/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394155008&sr=8-1&keywords=boolean+function+complexity

Comment: I've also found the old (1990) survey by Lovász useful for its conceptual stance; it is available from his web page at http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/commcomp.pdf

Comment: A more recent reference by Lee and Shraibman, also covers the methods to prove lower bound on quantum communication complexity
http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~troyjlee/survey_plain.pdf